# C: char user input in command prompt

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with reading char in C. I need to ask for user input until the user gives me 'x' or 'X' to stop.

```
char input[size] = {};

printf("Type 'x' or 'X' to stop input mode.\n");
while(strcmp(input,"x")!=0||strcmp(input,"X")!=0){
    printf(":");
scanf("\n%c", &input);
}
```

But still it does not work well.

Comment: quick question: what's the difference between `'x'` and `"x"` ?

Comment: There is no difference if you are doing ``input == 'x'`` or ``input == "x"``. However, if you are expecting ``"x"`` and ``"X"`` as actual input (with quotes), then the character ``'`` and ``"`` are different. In languages like C, you can wrap a string literal in double or single quote.  ``input  == 'x'``" means you are expecting the string to be the character letter x.

Comment: @CppLearner "I'm having a problem with **reading char** in C", there is no `char` in this code; I'm making sure that the OP understands the differences, because the question is self-contradictory .

Comment: I thought you were OP. You really should consider to use a more unique name. Fair point. I think Fernado covers it well. Haven't actually tested the code. But I won't deny Dinesh has the main issue covered as well.

Answer (score 1):

Edit- based on the comments.

```
char input = getchar();
while( input != 'x' && input != 'X' ) {
    // your code
    input = getchar();
}
```

Comment: That's the main issue and this is the correct answer. short-circuit.  Using ``||`` means OR. Imagine input is ``X``. The first condition doesn't match so program doesn't go on to the second comparison because the first comparison is good. Just completing Dinesh's answer.

Comment: @Dinesh add some initialization to the input variable.

Comment: @user3226156 try getchar(), putchar() instead of scanf() and printf(), the last two are overkills for reading/writing chars.

Comment: Using `int input` has advantages as `input` works directly with `isfuncitons()` and EOF may be tested.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` variable when used without square brackets is already a pointer, you don't need to use `&`.

Also `input` must be initialized before entering the while loop.

Comment: how to initialize an array of characters?

Comment: First think if you really need an array and look Dinesh's answer. If that's the case `char array[3] = {'a', 'b', '\0' };` but it is easier to write `char array[3] = "ab";` both options are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef CHAR_BASE

int main(){
    char input = 0;
    printf("Type 'x' or 'X' to stop input mode.\n");
    while(tolower(input) != 'x'){
        printf(":");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
    }
    return 0;
}
#else //STRING_BASE

int main(){
    char input[16] = {0};

    printf("Type 'x' or 'X' to stop input mode.\n");
    while(strcmp(input,"x") && strcmp(input,"X")){
        printf(":");
        scanf("%s", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```